# Why does outer reference in SQL subquery produce different results?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, apache-spark-sql

I run two SQL queries: The first one have an outer reference to the table inside subquery. In the second one I add the same table inside subquery. The results are different, it fails due to multiple rows.

The first one runs on Oracle, but fails on Spark-SQL. Therefore I am looking for a solution similar to Oracle SQl as in the first SQL code.

Query 1:

```
select *, 
(select N_CODE 
from table2 f 
where f.ID1 = (select min(f.ID1) 
               from table1 a left join table2 f on a.ID2 = f.ID2
               where a.ID2 = table1.ID2 
               ) 
) AS CODE

from table1
```

Query 2:

```
select *, 
(select N_CODE 
from table1 t, table2 f 
where f.ID1 = (select min(f.ID1) 
               from table1 a left join table2 f on a.ID2 = f.ID2
               where a.ID2 = t.ID2 
               ) 
) AS CODE

from table1
```

The second one is my solution to the first one in Spark SQL, but it fails on both Oracle and Spark. How can I run the first query on Spark SQL similar to Oracle?

Please do not modify the structure of the query.

Comment: Spark-SQL error: kind of "table1.ID2 is missing..."

Comment: Your queries are incomplete.  In particular, `table1` is not defined in the first one.  Don't make us guess what the queries really look like.

Comment: Do not use that ancient join syntax `from table1 t, table2 f`. Use `from table 1 t inner join table 2 f on ...` instead.
`

Comment: @Pavel: you suggestion produces: "single-row subquery returns more than one row"

Comment: @NasimiEldarov, probably, I can not say more without seeing the data. What's wrong with the first query? What error do you get when run it on Spark?

Comment: @Pavel: the error is: "cannot resolve '`table1.ID2`' given input columns"

Comment: Try rewriting it to `a.ID2` in the subquery.

Comment: @Pavel: How does it make sense? a.ID2 = a.ID2? Why does it work? Can you explain it please?

Comment: You declare an alias for `table1`: `table1 a` and then you write `a.ID2 = table1.ID2`, which is same as `a.ID2 = a.ID2`. The point was that Spark may not understand what `table1` is since you provided an alias for it.

Comment: In your first query you're trying to refer to the outer `table1` from within two levels of subquery; I'm slightly surprised Oracle doesn't mind that in this scenario, but it seems Spark SQL doesn't like it. Your second one isn't correlating properly but would probably have the same issue if it did. If you provide a [mre] we can suggest better ways to structure this, without the repeated references to the same tables or so many subqueries. (Oracle will throw ORA-00923 for both as written, incidentally...)

Comment: Thanks Pavel) It runs, but I will have to test it with Oracle.

Comment: Thanks Alex, the original code is too complicated, therefore I am not trying to restructure it)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oracle supports multiple inner queries but spark does not. The best way to overcome it is to split your super query into pieces and use join them.

For instance run this part and save it as a table3:

```
select min(table2 .ID1)
           from table1 a left join table2 f on a.ID2 = f.ID2
           where a.ID2 = t.ID2
from table2
```

Then use it for your main query:

```
....
where f.ID1 = table3
```